# Confidence Intervals for a matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, confidence-interval, boundaries

I have a series of experimental points. I performed a MLE for parameter estimation, Using a power law function, that gives me the 2 Parameters that best fit my data. Because of the model used, I had to implement an fminunc to the parameter estimation so the 95% confidence intervals have been estimated using the hessian matrix. So now I have "a=0.25" and "b=4" parameters of this function: y=a*x^(1/b) and their confidence intervals a = +_ 0.04 and b=+_ 0.5 . How do I plot the estimated curve and the relatives 95% confidence intervals bands??

I do not how to draw the upper and lower confidence boundaries. I don't think they are just the power law function with adding and removing the values of 95% CI to the estimated value.

Comment: do you think it would be posssible for the readers of your question to directly assess the code you have described in your question? if as they say an image is worth 1000 words, then the source file may also help a lot. Thanks